# time complexity of some recursive and none recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity, pseudocode

I have two pseudo-code algorithms:

```
RandomAlgorithm(modVec[0 to n − 1])
b = 0;
for i = 1 to n do
  b = 2.b + modVec[n − i];
for i = 1 to b do
  modVec[i mod n] = modVec[(i + 1) mod n];
return modVec;
```

Second:

```
AnotherRecursiveAlgo(multiplyVec[1 to n])
if n ≤ 2 do
  return multiplyVec[1] × multiplyVec[1];
return
  multiplyVec[1] × multiplyVec[n] + 
  AnotherRecursiveAlgo(multiplyVec[1 to n/3]) + 
  AnotherRecursiveAlgo(multiplyVec[2n/3 to n]);
```

I need to analyse the time complexity for these algorithms:
For the first algorithm i got the first loop is in O(n),the second loop has a best case and a worst case , best case is we have O(1) the loop runs once, the worst case is we have a big n on the first loop, but i don't know how to write this idea as a time complexity cause i usually get b=sum(from 1 to n-1) of 2^n-1 . modVec[n-1] and i get stuck here.

For the second loop i just don't get how to solve the time complexity of this one, we usually have it dependant on n , so we need the formula i think.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the dot notation, such as **2.b**?

Comment: What do you mean that you "usually get <ill-formed equation for b>" ?  Have you tried this different ways, and you get that answer with a majority of your methods?

Comment: the . is a multiplication @Prune

Comment: Ah.  Since you use **x** for multiplication elsewhere, I figured that the dot had to be something else.  I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @Prune why in the answer you didnt differentiate between n/3 and 2n/3 is it the same thing? is it proper to say that we take n=3^k and then we get c(n)=1+2O(log3O^k ) and then we get out the complexity? i just dont know how to formally say my idea.

Comment: This comment is on my answer, not on the original question.  You might move it down there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is a little strange, all right.
If it helps, envision **modVec** as an array of 1's and 0's.
In this case, the first loop converts this array to a value.
This is **O(n)**

For instance, (1, 1, 0, 1, 1) will yield b = 27.

Your second loop runs **b** times.  The dominating term for the value of b is **2^(n-1)**, a.k.a. **O(2^n)**.  The assignment you do inside the loop is **O(1)**.

---

The second loop *does* depend on **n**.  Your base case is a simple multiplication, **O(1)**.  The recursion step has three terms:

- simple multiplication
- recur on n/3 elements
- recur on n/3 elements  (from 2n/3 to the end is n/3 elements)

Just as your binary partitions result in **log[2]** complexities, this one will result in **log[3]**.  The base doesn't matter; the coefficient (two recursive calls) doesn't' matter.  2*O(log3) is still **O(log N)**.

Does that push you to a solution?

Comment: I think there's a typo in the parentheses, but you have the right idea.  The n/3 confusion is now edited into the answer.

Comment: how did you get that the dominating value is  2^(n-1) i got it too but i just need to justify it well i personnaly have done it but just don't know how to mathematicly justify it:( it's a proof.   (from 2n/3 to the end is n/3 elements) is this cause n-2n/3=n/3 i tough of this logic but semt kinda weird cause it sitll is 2n/3 i dont know why i'm struggling. thanks again for the followup

Comment: Yes, the second recursion is on (n - 2n/3) elements; that's n/3.  Simple math.

Comment: The highest-order term of **b** is **modVec[n-1]**, multiplied by 2 in each successive loop iteration: a total of **n-1** times.

Comment: when i usually get b= sum(from 1 to n) of 2pow(n-1) . modVec[n-i]. I feel like i'm dumb right now but i just can't go from this to the result in either algorithms. For the second algorithm i think i'll just go with 2(anotherrecur.....)+1 where the 1 is gonna get taken off

Comment: The critical part of the second one is that you chop the list into thirds.  can you draw the recursion call tree for lists of length 3, 9, and 27?  How many total calls are there?  2(another_recursion) needs to know how deep that call stack will go.  In this case, the depth is log[3](n).

Comment: i don't know if it's possible but if we take the hanoii algorithm the recursive relation becomes like C=C(N-1)+1+C(n-1) wich gives C(n-1) as the biggest value and we can do substituted countdown to find the complexity, can that be applied on this algorithm? Cause i personnally know how it does work, but just can't right a proper mathematical proof

Comment: Right -- but you have to include the tree depth in this!  Your current recursion is 1+C(n/3)+C(n/3).

Comment: i don't know why when i apply the master theoreme i get n pow(log3 2)

Comment: Neither do I, since you haven't posted how you got that.  Nor is this necessarily a problem ... assuming that I properly understand your notation.

Answer (score -1):

**First Loop**

To me this boils down to the O(First-For-Loop) + O(Second-For-Loop).

O(First-For-Loop) is simple = O(n).

O(Second-For-Loop) interestingly depends on n. Therefore, to me it's can be depicted as O(f(n)), where f(n) is some function of n. Not completely sure if I understand the f(n) based on the code presented.

The answer consequently becomes O(n) + O(f(n)). This could boil down to O(n) or O(f(n)) depending upon which one is larger and more dominant (since the lower order terms don't matter in the big-O notation.

**Second Loop**

In this case, I see that each call to the function invokes 3 additional calls...

The first call seems to be an O(1) call. So it won't matter.

The second and the third calls seems to recurses the function.
Therefore each function call is resulting in 2 additional recursions.

Consequently , the time complexity on this would be O(2^n).